# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path runtime error

Tags: java, netbeans

When I run my `Java` code shown below

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","low");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.web3d.j3d.browser.X3DJ3DBrowserFactoryImpl");
        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add((javax.swing.JPanel)x3dComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] {"test.x3d"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I get the following runtime error

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl$22.run(MasterControl.java:889)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:886)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:229)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativeConfigTemplate3D.<clinit>(NativeConfigTemplate3D.java:180)
    at javax.media.j3d.GraphicsConfigTemplate3D.<clinit>(GraphicsConfigTemplate3D.java:55)
    at org.web3d.j3d.browser.X3DBrowserJPanel.<init>(X3DBrowserJPanel.java:377)
    at org.web3d.j3d.browser.X3DJ3DBrowserFactoryImpl.createComponent(X3DJ3DBrowserFactoryImpl.java:358)
    at org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(BrowserFactory.java:263)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:42)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)
```

I have all the correct `jars` installed on the system which are `gluegen-rt, gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64, gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64, gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586, jhall, joal, joal-natives-linux-amd64, joalnatives-windows-amd64, gluegen-natives-windows-i586, jogl-all, jogl-natives-linux-amd64, jogl-natives-windows-amd64, jogl-natives-windows-i586, xj3d.browser_2.1.0-nps, xj3d.cadfilter_2.1.0-nps, xj3d.replica_2.1.0-nps, xj3d-2.1-3rdparty-nps, xj3d-2.1-nps, xj3d-core, xj3d-j3d, xj3d-script-base, xj3d-runtime, j3d-core-1.3.1` all within a file called `jar`. Within the `VM Options` in the `Run` section of the `Java` project I have `-Xmx450M -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jar"`

Comment: Did you add it to the build path?

Comment: @JClassic I have added it to the build path